# While executing the Linux script getting the jrcmd not found error

Tags: unix

I am getting the below error while executing the script

Ksh: line 1: jrcmd: not found

While executing the same command in weblogic server, I am getting the output, but while executing the same in script getting the not found error.

Can someone help here.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What script? Anyway, something is not on your PATH in some cases, or is not accessible for some reason. This is an environmental thing that we cannot assist with unless you share some of your environment. Where is this command? How would it be found via the command line? What makes invoking it from WL so special? There is some research to be done here.

Comment: Thanks for your response    please find the below script   #!/bin/ksh  process_id=`ssh -q account@servername -n "pa -ef |grep weblogic|great -v "grep""|awk '{print $2}'         ssh -q account@servername -n "jrcmd $process_id print_threads > /tmp/thread.txt"

Comment: See [ask]. Comments are not for question details. You should put everything relevant to the question in the text of the question with an [edit]. That being said, it looks a little like this is probably off-topic for SO. It may be more appropriate to research this on another SE site, like Unix and Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will check with unix.stackexchange.com